# Restart a Chrome App/Extension that is terminated through the task manager

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I understand that a Chrome app can't stop itself being terminated through the task manager but is there anyway that it can restart itself?

I'm looking at writing an app for a Public Session Chrome device and while I don't mind it being killed I do want it to reopen.  I can't yet find a way to do this either through code in the app itself or through a policy in the Google Admin Console.

Any suggestions?

**Edited To Add**
Following a suggestion I've attempted to use an alarm but it does not survive termination of the process, which is what I would expect.  Is there an OS level alarm/task that I can set?

This is a rough demo app that sets an alarm that will keep on opening a page.

```
console.log("background - Running");

setAlarm();

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
    onAlarm();
});


function setAlarm() {
    console.log("background.setAlarm");
    chrome.alarms.create("myAlarm", {when: Date.now() + (5 * 1000)} );
}

function openWindow() {
    console.log("background.openMainWindow");
    chrome.app.window.create('main.html', {
        id: 'MyWindowID',
        bounds: {
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            left: 100,
            top: 100
        },
        minWidth: 800,
        minHeight: 600
    });
}

function onAlarm() {
    console.log("background.onAlarm");
    openWindow();
    setAlarm();
}
```

Comment: Try chrome.alarms.create executed each second  inside setInterval callback that sets an alarm to Date.now()+2000

Comment: A quick demo app seems to show that the alarm is in the context of the application and does not survive its termination.

Comment: Thanks for coming back so quickly.  The sample code now included in the question is all inside the background page.

Comment: An earlier sample app was just using setInterval, and that wasn't surviving termination through the task manager either.

At the moment I'm locally loading an unpackaged app, and that does overcome the 1 minute alarm limit and it was working successfully until the app was terminated.  However I've adjusted the code to work with when: and I'm still not seeing it survive termination.

Thanks once again for your help with this.

I'll try a combination of setInterval and alarms.create...

Comment: maybe it works only for extensions, and you'll have to make an additional "resumer" extension that uses chrome.management API.

Comment: You're talking specifically about **Chrome OS** Public Session devices? Or?.. Seems strange that the user can access the task manager at all in this case - why not use a Kiosk?

Comment: I do think that I want a public session as I want the user to have the full Chrome Desktop experience rather than just a limited Kiosk app.

Answer (score 0):

There is an API chrome.runtime.reload() which can restart the Chrome App, I have not checked this API in any extension but its working as expected in Chrome Application